# Apache 2.4 LDAP authentication fails the first time, succeeds the second time but still returns HTTP 500

Tags: apache, authentication, ldap

When I try to authenticate using LDAP to ns-slapd, the first query fails and the following second one succeeds, but I receive HTTP 500 Internal server error (httpd 2.4.48).

```
Log (names redacted):
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/UXwnKN17

The above represents a SINGLE(!) login attempt to the web from browser.

Config here:

```
<Location />
  ...

  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.mycompany.com/dc=mycompany,dc=com"
  AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=Doc,cn=config"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxxxxxxx"
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
  Require ldap-group cn=Doc,ou=doc,ou=groups,dc=mycompany,dc=com
  Satisfy all
</Location>
```

Have you ever seen this? Have you found the cause/a solution?